# How to add texts and some contents inside image in an item grid list

Tags: flutter, dart

Now I have a widget of grid_list as the below one:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/products.dart';
import './product_item.dart';

class ProductsGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool showFavs;

  ProductsGrid(this.showFavs);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    final products = showFavs ? productsData.favoriteItems : productsData.items;
    return GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      itemCount: products.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            // builder: (c) => products[i],
            value: products[i],
            child: ProductItem(
            ),
          ),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 1,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and have am item list as the below one:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import '../providers/product.dart';
import '../providers/cart.dart';

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false);
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      child: GridTile(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
                arguments: product.id);
          },
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 2,
            child: Image.asset(
              product.imageUrl,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and give me a list as the below image

[image: my_list]

So Now I need to add some contents Over the picture like add Icons ad the corners and add some texts at the right or center of the image in every items to be some thing like the below image:

[image: template]

I hope some one could help me to solve this, I tried to add `GridTileBar` but I found that the height of this tile bar can't customize on it, by adding `footer`, `title`, and `trailing` as I need to add more contents, as I want to but an `IconButton` on every corner of the list item and also add some contents like the shown figure..

Comment: You can build a custom widget...using stack..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Stack` widget:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 250,
  height: 250,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: <Color>[
              Colors.black.withAlpha(0),
              Colors.black12,
              Colors.black45
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: Text(
          "Foreground Text",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the Stack Widget. Have a look at the docs. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html